# What does the turtle.tilt() method do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.tilt

```
def right():
    turtle.tilt(30)
def left():
    turtle.tilt(-30)
def move():
    turtle.fd(100)

wn.onkey(left,'Left')
wn.onkey(right,'Right')
wn.onkey(move,'Up')
wn.listen()
```

Answer: I'm trying to tilt a external shape(image file), which does not work as specified in the turtle.addshape section of the turtle documentation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.addshape

Comment: Have you tried executing the included example?

Answer (score 1):

The method does what it says on the tin: rotate the turtle *shape* without altering the heading of the turtle.

The turtle library displays a *shape* at the current turtle position on the screen. The default shape is an arrow, but several other options are available. The shape marks the current position, and is also indicative of the heading of the turtle.

So the shape can be *rotated*. It usually rotates together with the *heading* of the turtle; the direction that a *forward* command will move the turtle in. However, you can also rotate the shape independently from the heading, and `turtle.tilt()` does this by a certain number of degrees.

The documentation includes a short sample of code to demonstrate what this means. It sets the shape to a circle, then stretches out the shape to form an ellipsis. It then tilts the ellipsis by 30 degrees, moves the turtle forward to show that it still moves in the default direction (straight to the right), tilts the ellipsis again by another 30 degrees and moves forward once more, again showing that the tilt did not alter the direction.

However, if you are trying to use an *external GIF image* for the shape, that those shapes then *do not rotate*. From the [`turtle.addshape()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.addshape):

> **Note**: Image shapes do not rotate when turning the turtle, so they do not display the heading of the turtle!

Setting the shape tilt won't have any effect on such shapes, and they won't rotate to show the turtle heading either.

Comment: @F.Artal: there is no way of rotating an external image using turtle.

Comment: The default shape is *not* a turtle, it's 'classic' which is an arrow like shape.